# When I close the lid and open it later in the day, will command line programs resume?

Tags: command-line, python, resume, macbook-pro

I've been running a python script from the command line that's inserting data in a database for a couple of hours now. It will take at least half a day more before it's finished. However, I want to take the laptop with me to somewhere else. 
My sleep at closing lid settings (if they exist) are at default (I've never looked at them). If I close the lid and open it in 4 or 5 hours, will the python script resume from where it left off? If not, can this be set to work in the preferences somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should continue, if your script has any error-handling for loosing connection to the database (assuming off-site DB).

Though the exact behaviour is hard to predict without seeing the actual code. Sleeping the system may also leed to unexpected results in the script.

Comment: Thanks. It's a local database, so connection is not a problem.

Comment: @Niek - so you are testing this for all of us. Can you post your results? :)

Comment: @carbontax it continued where it left off after I opened it again